# Isolation Circuit Question - How does this feedback work?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, low-power, isolation

I am completely stumped. I have been troubleshooting this circuit for some time, and is what powers another circuit. The thing is, I have no idea how this thing works (not well as of late, due to other design errors past this section of the project.) I am new to the engineering side of things, and am a little lost when it comes to diagnosing circuits.

Apparently, this thing works, trouble is, the designer got canned, he left no notes, and I can't find anything else like it out there on the web. U12 is a UC3842B current mode controller, Q9 PN #TSM850N06CX RFG , and the optoisolator, U15 is PN# CNY17F-1S. But, I have no idea how the jeezless thing is getting proper feedback through the optoisolator. I also am not sure on how the isolated voltage is set, I can only assume T1 is acting like a 1:1 transformer, and I have no idea how the Isense pin is being used here.

The data sheet for U12 leaves something to be desired, and I think I just need a little guidance to how to figure out how things work. [image]

Comment: Start by looking up how the TL431 works. It's key to the operation. There are a load of TI datasheets and application notes over at https://www.ti.com/product/UC3842. The design is probably taken straight from one of those.

Comment: @Transistor Thank you so much for this, I have been staring at ON semiconductor sheets for days, because that's what digikey gave me, I had no idea TI had stuff on this too. I will go through this more, but some of the sheet already looks very similar to ON Semi's sheet. But TI might have more resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The thing is, I have no idea how this thing works*

The whole circuit is a flyback converter so there's your first term to start googling.

> *But, I have no idea how the jeezless thing is getting proper feedback
> through the optoisolator*

The TL431 acts like a voltage comparator - as soon as the "right" output voltage appears on the isolated output, it turns the UC3842 off (via the opto-isolator) and the DC output voltage drops a tad (under load) and then (microseconds later) the TL431 signals to the UC3842 that there is an under-voltage situation. This type of feedback can be a little unstable and can lead to a bang-bang control of a sort.

The threshold at which the "regulation" occurs is when the junction of R66 and R67 is 2.5 volts (that's the reference voltage inside the TL431). If you do the math, that allows 1.042 mA through R67 and R66 - this means that the output voltage regulation point is 21.25 volts nominally.

> *I have no idea how the Isense pin is being used here.*

Because a flyback converter circuit stores magnetic energy in the 1st half of the cycle without reference to the output winding, you have to use a current limiter to protect the transformer from core saturation - that is what Isense is being used for. A fixed amount of energy is stored in the primary winding and, in the 2nd half of the cycle, that energy is released from the secondary, via D2 into the output reservoir capacitor that appears to be missing in your circuit.

Comment: 21v is excactly what my tech was reporting. I must have missed the part mentioning 2.5v being vref for the tl431, I saw the (1+r2/r1)*(Vref), but was more stumped because I didn't know what Vref would be. I thank you tremendously.

Comment: having a bang-bang controller sounds sort of like it would kill the chip faster, and this circuit is supposed to last 5-10 years, in your eyes, would it be wise to propose to the higher ups to replace this with the recommended/practical application circuit from TI? This thing is currently only powering around 1-2watts of electronics behind it, off of 24vdc, and the practical app circuit is made for Mains power, at 45w,.

Comment: @JamesS It **may** operate a sort of bang-bang control (of a sort) but that's not a problem. The basic premise of switching with a pulse width modulated duty cycle is, in effect, like a bang bang control and there's nothing unreliable about that. That's how switching regulators work; on and off at high speed. It's a pretty standard circuit used in TVs and all sorts of consumer goods so if you want to replace it, do so because of a known unreliability or some form of cost removal exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The part was invented by Unitrode.  TI now owns Unitrode, so I'd consider them the primary source of design information.  The TI datasheet has detailed design guidance for each pin.

Your schematic has no output filter capacitor, and the voltage feedback input is shorted to GND.  Each of these errors makes the circuit unworkable, so I'd start by trying to find a more accurate schematic.  Or, reverse-engineer a schematic from the pc board (an excellent project for an intern or green designer).

App notes:

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua257/slua257.pdf?ts=1596126962964&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUC3842

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua162/slua162.pdf?ts=1596126974182&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUC3842

Comment: The lack of output capacitor is an issue, but it could be off-page.  The feedback pin is grounded intentionally, the TL431 provides the reference and error amplifier function and the second half of the optocoupler pulls down on the comp pin to close the loop.  So that's not an error that makes the circuit unworkable, it's working around the internal reference and feedback pin.

Comment: There is a capacitor past V_ISO, a 22uf tantalum cap. The other thing is, this circuit does work somehow, and currently when operating, runs at about 21v accross the secondary. This is why I am stumped. Immediately following this circuit is a 15v linear regulator. The circuit just makes no sense to me.

Comment: Well, if you still don´t understand after all the links and answers, here´s a brief explanation;  The reference voltage of the TL439 is 2.495V. If the feedback voltage (divider midpoint) rises above that, the 439 will pull current from the opto's diode, causing the opto's transistor on the other side to pull down on the comp pin (output of a gm amp so OK to pull down), causing the duty cycle to decrease thus keeping the output in regulation.  With your divider values the output voltage should be 2.495V+ 2.495/2.4*18=21.21V

Comment: Actually I mis-remembered, the error amp ISN'T a gm amp, but the datasheet states: COMP: Error amplifier compensation pin. Connect external compensation
components to this pin to modify the error amplifier output. The error
amplifier is internally current-limited so the user can command zero
duty cycle by externally forcing COMP to GROUND.  So still OK to modify the duty cycle by pulling COMP down with the opto.

Answer (score 1):

The description of loop compensation in the [UC3842](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3842.pdf?ts=1596126355309&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUC3842) datasheet is probably the best description  you will find of how the closed loop control **should** work. The loop bandwidth is limited by the frequency.

Gain is controlled by R69, in conjunction with the CTR of the opto-isolator, gain of the TL431 error amplifier etc. See equation 58:

[image]

Based on the datasheet, I think your values are off in a few places. R68 value looks wrong. 1pF seems pretty useless for C37.

In general as the output voltage increases, the TL431 conducts more and more, through R69 and the opto-isolator LED, causing the phototransistor to conduct which would normally increase the feedback voltage at Vfb via some resistors on the primary side.

However the designer seems to have done something very unorthodox by forcing feedback in through the output of the error amplifier (the comp pin).

If this thing doesn't work, you might be better off starting from scratch with the datasheet.

Comment: What datasheet is that equation from?

Comment: @JamesS There is one link in my answer and it take you to the datasheet.

Comment: My apologies, my page loaded in wrong and only actually showed the image, no text.